# Recommended practice for sharing fields between domain models

Tags: java, inheritance, domain-model

I'm working with a model that currently looks like this:

```
class Sign {
   enum Type { A, B }

   Color color;
   String textLine1;
   String textLine2;
   Type type;

   Sign(Type type, Color color, String textLine1, String textLine2) { ... }
}
```

A sign of type `A` has a color and 2 lines of text. A sign of type `B` has a color and only 1 line of text. Therefore they're instantiated like so:

```
Sign signA = new Sign(A, someColor, "line1", "line2");
Sign signB = new Sign(B, someColor, "line1", null);
```

When working with these instances, code checks for the `type` property and reads the appropriate fields.

I think this approach may be flawed as a `B` sign should not expose properties it doesn't hold (line2). It's also unsightly to be passing `null` to a bunch of properties it doesn't care about at instantiation time.

I'm wondering if it would be appropriate to use inheritance instead, where a base class would contain the shared fields and the type.

```
abstract class Sign {
    enum Type { A, B }

    Color color;
    String textLine1;
    Type type;

    Sign(Type type, Color color, String textLine1) { ... }
} 

class SignA extends Sign {
    String textLine2;      

    SignA(Color color, String textLine1, String textLine2) {
        super(A, color, textLine1);
        this.textLine2 = textLine2;
    }
} 

class SignB extends Sign { 
    SignB(Color color, String textLine1) {
        super(B, color, textLine1);
    }
}
```

Is the above a recommended pattern for modeling models of this type? Note that these models have no behavior and are purely bags of properties.

Comment: What are you doing with that enum? That looks like a code smell that you will be doing a bunch of if statements with casting.

Comment: Today, the enum value is used to know if we should expect a `textLine2`. So yes, a bunch of if statements. I was thinking that in my proposed approach I'd check the type enum, cast `Sign` to one of the subtypes and work with that. I hadn't considered the `instanceof` usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance is the right way to model this domain, however enumeration is not necessary here. You already have distinctive characteristic of each sign - the type, which can be checked via instanceof or via reflection.

Polymorphism example:

```
abstract class Sign { 
    abstract void printType();
}
class SignA extends Sign {
    void printType() {
        System.out.println("Sign A");
    }
}
class SignB extends Sign {
    void printType() {
        System.out.println("Sign B");
    }
}
...
Sign sign = ...
sign.printType();
```

`instanceof` example:

```
Sign s = ...
if (s instanceof SignA) { ... } 
else if (s instanceof SignB) { ... } 
else {
   // safety check for future code modifications, in which you add new type 
   // but forget to add a handler
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Sign type " 
       + s.getClass().getName() 
       + " not supported");
}
```

Reflection example (Java 8):

```
Map<Class<? extends Sign>, Consumer<Sign>> processors = ...;
...
processors.put(SignA.class, s -> System.out.println("Sign A"));
processors.put(SignB.class, s -> System.out.println("Sign B"));
...
Sign sign = ...;
Consumer<Sign> processor = processors.get(sign.getClass());
processor.accept(sign);
```

Answer (score 1):

If these are only "bags of properties", I'd go with the simplest solution:

```
class SignB {
    Color color;
    String line1;

    SignB(Color color, String line1) { ... }
}

class SignA extends SignB {
    String line2;

    SignA(Color color, String line1, String line2) {
        super(color, line1);
        this.line2 = line2;
    }
```

A less restrictive approach (you can't enforce 1 or 2 lines) but more generic (you always iterate over the available lines):

```
class Sign {
    Color color;
    List<String> lines;

    Sign(Color color, String... lines) { ... }
}

Sign signA = new Sign(Color.RED, "hello");
Sign signB = new Sign(Color.BLUE, "hello", "world");
```

A third approach. However I never used such an approach and I don't know how viable it is:

```
class Sign {
    Color color;
    String line1;
    Optional<String> line2;

    Sign(Color color, String line1) {
        this(color, line1, null);
    }

    Sign(Color color, String line1, String line2) {
        this.color = color;
        this.line1 = line1;
        this.line2 = Optional.ofNullable(line2);
    }
}
```